# nginx-ingress rewrite-target to /api not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i am trying to get api as location (/api) to work with intress settings

this is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-dev
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
    
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'dev.example.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-ruby
            port: 3000
```

when i curl dev.example.com/api/check_version
i get error

```
I, [2021-12-01T16:43:35.776502 #13]  INFO -- : [7253cca0b88503d625af527db32eb92e] Started GET "/api/check_serverr" for 10.42.1.228 at 2021-12-01 16:43:35 +0300
F, [2021-12-01T16:43:35.779603 #13] FATAL -- : [7253cca0b88503d625af527db32eb92e]
[7253cca0b88503d625af527db32eb92e] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/check_version"):
```

if i add annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

get error

```
I, [2021-12-01T16:49:11.153280 #13]  INFO -- : [7832de5c07e3a173ddc86ebab5735cec] Started GET "/" for 10.42.1.228 at 2021-12-01 16:49:11 +0300
F, [2021-12-01T16:49:11.154435 #13] FATAL -- : [7832de5c07e3a173ddc86ebab5735cec]
[7832de5c07e3a173ddc86ebab5735cec] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
```

how to make a rewrite correctly in this case?

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the expected incoming url path and what it needs to be rewritten to?

Comment: or rather what is the expected url path and what does your application expect to receive?

Comment: whitout ingress its work like this   dev.example.com/check_version
in kubernetes im trying create path /api fo my ruby dev.example.com/api
url should look like this: dev.example.com/api/check_version but rails havent route)

Comment: something like this? `path: /api(/|$)(.*)` and the `rewrite-target: /$2`

Comment: this way /api is stripped off before the request is sent to the backend, and requesting `/api/check_version` will become `/check_version` before it comes to the backend

Comment: thank u very math u. it work!!

Comment: where can i read about it?

Comment: [This document](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) seems like a good place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the following seems to have fixed the issue.

You are looking to strip off the `/api` part off before the request is sent to the backend, thus requesting `/api/check_version` will become `/check_version` before it hits the backend:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

...<omitted>...

      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
```